# How can I do role based access for the pages using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, role-base-authorization

I want to do a role based access for the pages in AngularJS.

Based on the role pages should be shown to the user.

Can any give me an example? Which should be a best solution.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I'll shoot for a shared service, coupled to a simple document oriented database system

Comment: I have not tried anything. I can found some thing over the internet related to this but cannot get complete code over the internet

Comment: It's unlikely that someone here will write you an entire role-based authorization tool

Answer (score 1):

To access the page based on the role is very easy.

1. Suppose if the web/dashboard have three roles like admin, support, employee.
2. assign the field as userrole to the users.
3. Now assign the roles for those pages as ng-if="userrole=='admin'" or vice versa
4. now based on the roles the pages are accessible

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a look at (in the following steps):

1. Decide on an approach for accessing the current users role.
2. Look into ui-router, specifically it's Resolve method.
3. Run some third function inside the Resolve method to see if the user is of the correct role, and handle your cases in what way you will.

Something I worked on a while back had an Authenticate method running in the Resolve method, you may want to have a look at that for reference. This was not role based however, but it may give you a nudge in the right direction.

Routes: 
https://github.com/kasperlewau/metalmarket/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/config/routes.js

Auth Service: https://github.com/kasperlewau/metalmarket/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/app/services/auth.js

If anyone has a better idea for role based / logged-in based authentication, I'm all ears.